# Draw call returned Invalid argument. Expect corruption

Tags: pi-4, yocto

I have raspberry pi 4 2G Ram I m using Boot2Qt yocto. Everything is working good, but when I launch our Qt Application

```
./3d-text -platform eglfs
```

then below error occurrs:

> Draw call returned Invalid argument. Expect corruption.

But when I launch like this

```
 ./3d-text -platform linuxfb
```

it will work.

Comment: Probably you have to enable the eglfs feature of your yocto installation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760009/how-to-enable-eglfs-plugin-in-yocto-setup-using-yoctometa-qt5-for-riotboard

Comment: hello thanks  for your reply as I mention I m using boot2qt its already enabled eglfs my question is I want to switch wayland to X11 display server how to do that ?

Comment: Oh, that comes as a surprise to me. My English is bad, I know, but I never expected that your question was how to change Wayland to X11  DS. And sorry for not carefully reading the question (boot2qt).  I fear I can not help you with that question, but as far as I know neither framebuffers nor eglfs need a display server. (That's the reason for the fact, that they can only be used in full screen mode.) So switching the DS with this flags would not work, if I'm right. And it is also impossible to use eglfs without a HDMI or DSI connection. I2C or SPI displays won't work.

Comment: Yes I m using HDMI waveshare 7" with usb touch 1024x600 I have update kernel also I dont know from where error occurs Please Help us Thanks Nome